# How to install CollabNet Subversion Edge 4.0.10 in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, svn

Can anyone tell me the procedure to install [CollabNet Subversion Edge 4.0.10](http://www.collab.net/downloads/subversion) on Ubuntu 14.04?

I am new to Ubuntu.

Comment: In what format is the downloaded file? I tried downloading but they said I had to sign up first - of course I didn't.

Comment: @Parto,The downloaded file is `CollabNetSubversionEdge-4.0.10_linux-x86.tar.gz`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install a .tar.gz (or .tar.bz2) file?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-do-i-install-a-tar-gz-or-tar-bz2-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a dedicated [page](http://help.collab.net/index.jsp?topic=/csvn/action/installcsvnonlinux.html) hosted by collabnet on this topic.

How ever summarizing the process:

1. If you have Java installed. Set you JAVA_HOME to point your installation directory. If you don't have java installed then install it first.
2. Extract your files from archive
   `tar -vzxf CollabNetSubversionEdge<your_version>.tar.gz`
3. Change directory and execute executable `csvn/bin/csvn start`

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I did, step by step:

1. Installed a "next-next-next" implementation of Ubuntu 14.04 server.
2. Logged in as root on the console, then ran the following command:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install openssh-server
   ```
3. Next we create a non-root user. In this example we are using svnadministrator .

   ```
   sudo adduser svnadministrator
   ```
4. (couple of prompts for this procedure, password/user, detail, etc.)

   ```
   sudo visudo
   ```
5. Look for--->  `root ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL` and then below that put in the entry below:

   ```
   svnadministrator ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
   ```
6. Save your changes.
7. LOGGED OUT OF ROOT and then log in as the non-root user you created (svnadministrator in this example).

   !!!The notes for subversion says to try and do it as a non-root user, so I did.!!!

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java  
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
8. (You can change the "6" to "7" or "8" in the next command, depending on the Java version you want. SVN seemed to want 6)

   ```
   sudo apt-get install oracle-java6-installer
   ```
9. (Agree to terms.)

   ```
   sudo apt-get install oracle-java6-set-default
   ```
10. Set the home variable.

    ```
    export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-oracle/
    ```
11. Get the installer from http://www.collab.net/svnedge. 
    You'll need to login in and/or create an account.

    (I downloaded it to my Windows box then SCP'd it over to my Linux box)

    ```
    tar -zxf CollabNetSubversionEdge-1.1.0_linux-x86.tar.gz
    ```
12. The tar.gz file is unpacked to the csvn directory.

    ```
    cd csvn  
    bin/csvn start
    ```
13. (Wait a minute or so...)

> ```
> http://192.168.x.x:3343/csvn/login/auth
> ```

DONE!

Comment: Why do you use a nonstandard Java?